# Closing colorbox and navigation to other page from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here s what i am doing, creating a link from the colobox and upon closing the color i want to navigate to other page from the page where i am right now So the code below closes the colorbox but it does not navigation to the other Page

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".editquotelinenow").click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var mainID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        window.parent.$.colorbox.close();
        window.location.href='index.cfm?action=linkproducts&ID='+mainID+'&ibase='+id+'&icode=sync';
    });
});
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here, even i had moved the parent below the window.location but no effect,

also i tried adding the `window.parent.location.href=`, but also not working, i am missing something silly here, not sure what, please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is purpose of using window.parent and what is colorbox? Below code works fine.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".editquotelinenow").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var mainID = $(this).attr('data-id');

        window.location.replace('index.cfm?action=linkproducts&ID='+mainID+'&ibase='+id+'&icode=sync');
    });
});
```

Comment: colorbox is just like a alternative of fancybox